# Nowhere vanishing harmonic 1-forms on 3-manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, hodge-theory

Consider $(S^1 \times \Sigma^2, g)$, where $g$ is any Riemannian metric on the compact and closed $3$-manifold $S^1 \times \Sigma^2$.

> Question:
> Does there always exist a nowhere vanishing harmonic $1$-form on $S^1 \times \Sigma^2$?
> If the answer to this question is No, how about the generalisation to $k$-parameter families of metrics?

So far I tried to find an example of a harmonic $1$-form on $T^3=S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$ that *does* have a zero but did not succeed.

I have cross-posted this question to: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407340/nowhere-vanishing-harmonic-1-forms-on-3-manifolds.

Comment: By non-vanishing you mean nowhere-vanishing?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: I made a bit of progress: using Calabi's characterisation of harmonic $1$-forms from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319107/can-a-harmonic-function-on-a-topological-cylinder-have-critical-points, I can get harmonic $1$-forms with zeros on some manifolds. Take a some 3-manifold and a Morse function $f$ with exactly one minimum and maximum. Attach a 3-handle connecting the minimum and maximum. $f$ cannot be extended to the new manifold, but $df$ can and is intrinsically harmonic by Calabi's theorem. If $f$ had other critical points (which may or may not be the case), then $df$ has zeros.

Comment: The answer looks to be no. A closed nowhere vanishing 1-form (you could try to generalize the Tishler's theorem) will give you a fiberation to S^1 and the 1-form will be the pull-back of the S^1 factor. It looks to me that for genus>1 Riemann surface, the fiberation is unique. Thus, you could choose any Riemannian metric to make the S^1 factor closed 1-form not harmonic, then for these metric, it doesn't have the thing you want.

Comment: @SiqiHe I don't understand how to complete your argument. (1) The closed 1-form coming from the $S^1$-fibration may not be harmonic, but its cohomology class contains a harmonic representative. How can I say anything about its zeros? (2) if the Riemann surface has genus$>1$, there are other harmonic forms not in the homology class of the closed 1-form coming from the $S^1$-fibration. I don't know how to say anything about their zeros.

Comment: @user505117 Let's consider the easiest case and here is only a suggestion. Let's fix a Riemannian metric g over $Y:=S^2\times S^1$, suppose there exists a harmonic 1-form $v$ over $Y$ such that $v$ has no zeroes, then using $v$, we could define a map $f:Y\to S^1$ such that $v=f^{\star}d\theta$(This construction doesn't need to use the Riemannian metric.) However, the harmonic condition for $v$ means extra restriction for the Riemannian metric $g$, this gives a contradiction. (I think you could use local perturbation of $g$ to make this contradiction argument.)

Comment: @user505117 For (2), you could study this for generic metric, in which every harmonic 1-form will have isolated zeros. The "generic" closed 1-form could define a Novikov Morse theory and the topological condition will let you have zeroes.

Comment: @SiqiHe I'm trying to understand the $S^2 \times S^1$ case. I agree that the condition for $v$ to be harmonic imposes a restriction on $g$, say an equation $F(g)=0$. Choosing a different metric $\tilde{g}$ gives a different harmonic $1$-form $\tilde{v}$ and a different restriction $\tilde{F}$. $\tilde{g}$ will not, in general, satisfy $F(\tilde{g})=0$, but that is no contradiction. There is a neighbourhood of $g$ in the space of all metrics such that the uniquely determined harmonic $1$-form for each metric has no zeroes. I can't put my finger on it, but that seems to be at odds with your (1).

Comment: @user505117 Let me try to explain the case $Y=S^1\times S^2$: let $v$ be a closed 1-form on $Y$ without zeros, then it has to be $d\varphi$, where $\varphi$ is the $S^1$ direction coordinates. By Tishler's theorem, there exists a map $f:Y\to S^1$ such that $v=f^{\star}d\theta$. It looks to me that $f$ has to be the projection into $S^1$ or winding $n$ times in $S^1$ direction. Then $v=f^{\star}d\theta=nd\varphi$. The above discussion don't need any metric. However, to make $d\varphi$ not be co-closed, you only need to perturb the metric locally, which gives a counter example for your question.

Comment: @user505117 In addition "here is a neighbourhood of g in the space of all metrics such that the uniquely determined harmonic 1-form for each metric has no zeroes." Could you explain why this is true in $S^2\times S^1$?

Comment: "let $v$ be a closed 1-form on $Y$ without zeros, then it has to be $d \varphi$, where $\varphi$ is the $S^1$ direction coordinates." I think $v$ and $d \varphi$ can differ by something exact, i.e. $v=d \varphi+d g$, where $g$ is a function on $Y$. If $||g||_{C^0}$ is small enough compared to $d \varphi$, then this also has no zeros. Does your argument cover this scenario? Also, $v$ could be a multiple of $d \varphi$, like $2\cdot d \varphi$, but you can get rid of that by normalising, so I'm not worried about this.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a full answer, but I just wanted to add holonomy to what you already found and it became to long for a comment.

The Bochner Theorems say, that for a Riemann manifold $(M,g)$ with $Ric \geq 0$ any harmonic $1$-form is parallel.

In this case, if $\omega$ is harmonic and there exists $p \in M$ with $\omega_p = 0$ then $\omega = 0$ globally. That is why you cannot find non-trivial harmonic $1$-forms on $T^3$ having zeroes.

If $Ric = 0$, then $1$-forms are harmonic iff they are parallel. Then finding a nowhere vanishing harmonic $1$-form is the same as finding a nontrivial parallel vector field, which exists if and only if
$$ Hol((M,g)) \subset SO(m-1) \subset SO(m).$$

So the metrics constructed in Calabi's Theorem [you linked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319107/can-a-harmonic-function-on-a-topological-cylinder-have-critical-points) for nontrivial transitive $1$-forms with zeroes, cannot have $Ric \geq 0$ globally.

Comment: Great observation! I think that in the case of $M=T^3$, we can't even have $Scal \geq 0$ globally, as that would contradict the Schoen-Yau Torus Rigidity theorem. I found this statement as Theorem 2.1 in "Conjectures on Convergence and Scalar Curvature" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.10093.pdf) but didn't find the original reference.